# How does the ping command differentiate between its ICMP responses and anothers?

Tags: networking, ip, ping, icmp

If I have two shells open each pinging the same host, how do the two shells differentiate between the ICMP responses coming back for each shell?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The request includes a 2-byte Identifier field, which must match in the reply. This is separate from the Sequence field. You can see it described in [RFC 792](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc792)